# angular bootstraping app inside ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I want to know if is possible to import a angular app inside a ng-view(through script tag) and then bootstrap it?.

I want this because I need to load a second app that the js files are restricted and only can be imported into the DOM only after some validations against the server side, because the js file with the second app contains sensitive information about the logic of my app.

Edit:
The consist of 4 logical angular apps (1 for each user type) thats the reasso  why intended to use ng view to render on the fly the screen and the js files.

There is any another way to import the js files and views on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

From Angular docs, Angular apps cannot nested each other. See that https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

But you can use multiple apps inside the same page such as:

```
<div ng-app="app1">stuff</div>
<div ng-app="app2">stuff2</div>
```

Comment: I seen that info on angular docs. The idea is not expose the js files of the other app if certain validation is not done before (request to server if is logged in sending a json web token stored on localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

you can try implementing that sensitive logic in

```
app.bootstrap = function(dependecies here) {

});
```

or you can use [angular provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)